# MS-Access Open record as it is created

Tags: ms-access

I have made a booking system that allows the user to book a ferry trip. Once the user has created their booking another window pops up with a confirmation that displays the info they put in and also the calculated price depending on what they put int. All of this is fine but I had an issue with it not going to the correct record after creation. I entered:=`"[Booking Number]=" & [Booking Number]`into the WHERE CLAUSE on the MACRO for the button before this window appears hoping this would work.

However, the issue I now face is the Confirmation Window is Empty. I think this is because it is trying to capture a record that has not been created yet but as I am not experienced with Access (literally started yesterday) I do not know how to go around this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing the WHERE CLAUSE on the macro.

On the confirmation form, On_Open I added a refresh before going to the record. This solved the problem.